# django filter on multiple GET parameters

Tags: python, django, forms, get

I have a search field and two extra search parameters (category and platform) on the side of the results on my search page.

my queryset looks like this on the list view:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    category = self.request.GET.get('category')
    platform = self.request.GET.get('platform')

    text_query = (
        Q(name__icontains=query) |
        Q(category__name__icontains=query) |
        Q(tags__name__icontains=query)
    )

    object_list = Results.objects.all()

    if query:
        object_list = object_list.filter(
            text_query
        )

    if category:
        object_list = object_list.filter(Q(category__name=category))

    if platform:
        if platform == "windows":
            object_list = object_list.select_related('versions').latest().filter(windows=True)
        elif platform == "linux":
            object_list = object_list.select_related('versions').latest().filter(linux=True)
        elif platform == "mac":
            object_list = object_list.select_related('versions').latest().filter(mac=True)

    return object_list
```

I know the last part can be one line with `exec`, but this does not work because you cant filter the result of a filter (`object_list`).

What is the best way to filter based on multiple `GET` parameters?

Comment: use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I will look into it thanks